# Realtime tracking with Rest Api GeoJson & Leaflet-realtime

Tags: dictionary, real-time

I have created a REST API server that returns data in GEOJSON format.
Using Leaflet-realtime, I only display the last entered json data on the map. I would like to receive only the last data entered but for each "idResource".

```
enter code here
{"type":"Feature","_id":"5e9cf09f9086a14d2021a911","geometry":{"type":"Point","_id":"5e9cf09f9086a14d2021a912","coordinates":[48.84500325878673,-60.14731106040295]},"properties":{"tipoRisorsa":"Drones","_id":"5e9cf09f9086a14d2021a913","nomePilota":"Pinco Panco","marcaDrone":"CPR03","idRisorsa":1},"__v":0},{"type":"Feature","_id":"5e9cf0a99086a14d2021a914","geometry":{"type":"Point","_id":"5e9cf0a99086a14d2021a915","coordinates":[45.84500325878673,-61.14731106040295]},"properties":{"tipoRisorsa":"Drones","_id":"5e9cf0a99086a14d2021a916","nomePilota":"Pinco Panco","marcaDrone":"CPR03","idRisorsa":1},"__v":0},{"type":"Feature","_id":"5e9cf0ee9086a14d2021a91b","geometry":{"type":"Point","_id":"5e9cf0ee9086a14d2021a91c","coordinates":[49.85500325878673,-45.14731106040295]},"properties":{"tipoRisorsa":"Drones","_id":"5e9cf0ee9086a14d2021a91d","nomePilota":"Ciccio Ollo","marcaDrone":"CCA05","idRisorsa":2},"__v":0},{"type":"Feature","_id":"5e9cf1009086a14d2021a91e","geometry":{"type":"Point","_id":"5e9cf1009086a14d2021a91f","coordinates":[50.85500325878673,-42.14731106040295]},"properties":{"tipoRisorsa":"Drones","_id":"5e9cf1009086a14d2021a920","nomePilota":"Ciccio Ollo","marcaDrone":"CCA05","idRisorsa":2},"__v":0}
```